# Meteor template dynamically inserted callback

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to run a callback on a template after it's dynamically inserted? I've found the `rendered` and `created` methods on a template, but those run for every instance of a template on the initial render.

Think of a todo list where clicking "Add" should `insert` an item into the `ToDos` collection, wait for Meteor to update the contents of an `#each` loop, then focus an input element on the newly added element. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use [animation hooks](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw) for this.

Comment: If you are adding an item into the collection, that data is reactive and automatically gets updated on screen. I think what you really want is to run a callback after the insert is done. (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) The `results` parameter passed into the callback contains the document, which you can use to do whatever you want with the newly-added element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tracker.afterFlush` to do things after the page updates. So for example:

```
Items.insert({...});
Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
  // In here, the UI has already been updated
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this may solve a slightly different problem I was having with calling bootstrap methods initializing dropdowns after adding new elements to the page.